# Design two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have designed the following but I am looking for a simpler way to design it (currently when I am going to retrieve list of subcategories that user is interested I should have different queries for each type of sport) :

User table has users info each user is interested in number of sport categories, each category has different subcategories, user can be interested in category (all subcategories) or just a number of subcategories of a particular category.

```
User      UserID                                         12

Sport     CategoryID Category                            1 Aquatic,    2 Running 

Aquatic   SubCategoryID SubCategory,CategoryID           1 Swimming 1, 2 Surfing 2 

Running   SubCateogryID SubCategory,CategoryID           1 200m 2,     2 300m 2 

LikeSport UserID CateogryID SubCategoryID                12 1 1,       12 2 nill
```

It shows user with ID 12 likes Aquatic sport but just Swimming and likes all type of Running Sports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Users:                         UserID
Categories:                    CategoryID, CategoryName
Subcategories:                 SubcategoryID, SubcategoryName
CategoriesSubcategories:       CategorySubcategoryID, CategoryID, SubcategoryID
LikeSports:                    UserID, CategorySubcategoryID
```

Comment: i thought each category is a sport in this context. So `categories` and `sports` tables would be the same

Comment: @arunmoezhi Yes, it seems so but the names are misleading; perhaps OP could clarify?

Comment: @user1327861 thanks for your answers, Acquatic and Running are categories of Sport but each have their own subcategories. I suppose if I should rename the Sport table to Category table for better illustration. (There are different sport categories such as Acquatic, Football, Running, ....each with their own sub categories Swimming, Waterploo - indoor, outdoor - 100m, 200m  user might be interested in a category like Acquatic or number of subcategories such as indoor from Football and 100 m from running)

Comment: Thanks for clarification, changed answer -- it is similar to the answer by @arunmoezhi just more normalized.

Answer (score 1):

user Table:
userId,userName

category Table:
categoryId, categoryName

subCategory Table:
subCategoryId,subCategoryName,categoryId (FK)

like Table:
userId(FK),categoryId(FK),subCategoryId(FK)